# How to pass a sparse tensor to the Dense Layer in TF 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, valueerror

I am using TF 2.0.

**WORKING:**

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers

inputs = layers.Input(shape=(256,), sparse=False, name='name_sparse')
x = layers.Dense(32, name="my_layer")(inputs)
print(x)
```

Output: `Tensor("my_layer/Identity:0", shape=(None, 32), dtype=float32)`

**NOT WORKING:**

If I change sparse to `True` in the above code, the output changes to:

`ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to Dense should be defined. Found None.`

How can I pass a sparse tensor to the Dense layer in TF2.0. It works well in TF1.14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because when input tensor is sparse shape of this tensor evaluates to `(None,None)` instead of `(256,)`

```
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(256,), sparse=True, name='name_sparse')
print(inputs.shape) 
# output: (?, ?)
```

This also seems to be an open [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23748).

One solution is to write custom layer sub-classing Layer class (Refer [this](https://medium.com/dailymotion/how-to-design-deep-learning-models-with-sparse-inputs-in-tensorflow-keras-fd5e754abec1)).
As a **work-around** (tested on tf-gpu 2.0.0) adding batch-size in input layer works fine:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(256,), sparse=True, name='name_sparse', batch_size=32)
print(inputs.shape) # (32, 256)
x = layers.Dense(32, name="my_layer")(inputs)
print(x) # Tensor("my_layer_10/BiasAdd:0", shape=(32, 32), dtype=float32)
```